# how to redirect to a page in Javascript or Jquery with CSS

Tags: javascript, redirect

I tryied multiple piece of code to redirect to another HTML page in my .js file :

```js
windows.location.href("../index.html")
```

(for example)

The page load but not the CSS wont load.
Can someone help me ?

Comment: I doubt the CSS problem is related to the redirect. Please share the code for the problematic page, including the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if you want the redirect to happen in a new tab.
and this to open in the same tab window.open("https://stackoverflow.com/users/13082963/purke-gopinand?tab=profile", "_self");

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  window.open("https://stackoverflow.com/users/13082963/purke-gopinand?tab=profile");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function redirect_Page () {
        var tID = setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.href = "https://www.google.de/";
            window.clearTimeout(tID);
        }, 5000);
    }
```

or

```
    setTimeout(function () {
    window.open('https://www.google.de/', '_blank');
}, 5000);
```